# .gitignore not ignoring files on current server

Tags: django, git, unix, digital-ocean

I'm trying to import my Bitbucket repo into my Digital Ocean Django server (next to `env`, `static` and `manage.py`. But when I do `git add .` inside the server directory, and then `git status`, it still shows the `env` files there. Any reason why this is happening?

Edit:

**.gitignore**

```
env/
/env
/bin
/lib
/media
/static
/include
/reports
.DS_Store
*.pyc
celerybeat-schedule.db
__pycache__/
db.sqlite3
settings.py
```

Comment: can you post `.gitignore` code here?

Comment: Added in my edit

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why are you doing `git add` *on the server*? You're supposed to do that in your development environment.

Comment: Yes you're right @DanielRoseman however I've tried everything. `git clone myrepo.git .` returns `fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.` notice I've added the dot at the end so I don't make an extra parent folder

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in this format:

```
env/env
env/bin
env/lib
etc.
```